# listbox not clearing unless messagebox is used

Tags: c#

I have some code that takes input from a TXT. For some reason, the listbox does not clear unless messagebox is used. Here is code:

```
private void addRelease()
 {
     if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
     {
         listBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Clear()));
         MessageBox.Show("f");
     }
     else
     {
         listBox1.Items.Clear();
         MessageBox.Show("f");
     }
     try
     {
         string[] txtLine = File.ReadAllLines("output.txt");
         string firstLine = txtLine[0];
         string filter = @"\d+";
         Match ifCorrect = Regex.Match(firstLine, filter);
         if (ifCorrect.Success)
         {
             if (int.Parse(ifCorrect.ToString()) != ver)
             {
                 ExecuteProcess();
             }
         }

         foreach (string line in txtLine)
         {

             if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
             {
                 listBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Add(line)));
             }
             else
             {
                 listBox1.Items.Add(line);
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     }
 }
```

Listbox should of cleared. Here is a video:
https://imgur.com/YkaOeT5

If you need full code, I can provide

Comment: can you try to embed the whole logic in one single `Action` delegate? that way the UI won't be confused by multiple threads updating but one single thread-safe block invoked by the main thread. By whole logic I meant clearing the listbox and parsing the text content to feed it

Comment: It clearly does clear...and then promptly fills back up; without the messagebox. Do you mean you want it to be empty AFTER it's done doing all things?

Comment: I tried to use the action delegate and its the same thing. For Idle_Mind, lets say I click Windows 10, I changed my mind I then I click Windows 8.1. It should clear previous data and show new data. Like when I add the message boxes, but I don't want the messageboxes to be there.

Comment: If you want to be able to CANCEL a currently running operation, then you add in a check to some kind of boolean flag inside your `for` loop. If you want to use a more robust method, then look up [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) or a similar Task based approach.